# Send messages to specific devices using firebase functions

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried sending a specific message to a client device using node js and firebase functions. But when I tried executing the function, it came back with an error saying:

> Error. Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array.

The image is shown below.

[image: Database Snapshot]

I was guessing it's from my JS code. So I am posting that too. What I am actually do is retrieving a data from a specific node to be used when a totally different node is being written. So I am gonna post the JS code before the database screenshots.

```
exports.sendNotification8 = functions.database.ref('/Users/{user_id}/Notifications/')
    .onWrite(( change,context) =>{

    var user_id = context.params.user_id;

    // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    var eventSnapshot = change.after.val();

    var device_token = admin.database().ref('/Users/{user_id}/device_token').once('value');

    return device_token.then(result => {

    var token_id = result.val();

    var str = eventSnapshot.from + " : " + eventSnapshot.message;
    console.log(eventSnapshot.from);

    var payload = {
        data: {
            name: str,
            title: eventSnapshot.from,
            click_action: "Chats"

        }
    };

    // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(function (response) {
            // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
            // contents of response.
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            return;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });

    });

    });
```

And below is my database screenshots...[image: Database Snapshot]

So that's how I am retrieving the **device_token** node. From the user that had the newest data written to his/her notifications node. Please help. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Wow. This has been torture. But it finally worked. I got something like this.

```
exports.sendNotification8 = functions.database.ref('/Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notifications_id}')
    .onWrite((change,context) =>{

    var user_id = context.params.user_id;
    console.log(user_id);

    // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    var eventSnapshot = change.after.val();

    var device_token = admin.database().ref('/Users/'+user_id+'/device_token').once('value');

    return device_token.then(result => {

    var token_id = result.val();

    console.log(token_id);

    var str = eventSnapshot.message;
    console.log(eventSnapshot.from);

    var payload = {
        data: {
            name: str,
            title: eventSnapshot.from,
            click_action: "Chats"

        }
    };

    // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(function (response) {
            // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
            // contents of response.
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            return;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });

    });

    });
```